# Tomcat: usuario no tiene privilegios suficientes o objeto no encontrado

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc

Estoy tratando de acceder a un archivo access desde una aplicación web utilizando el driver jdbc ucanaccess 4.0.3.
Los tests al construir el jar utuilizado se ejecutan sin problema.

Application Context en jar file:

```
<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan base-package="cat.dinet.lblchem.sec" />

<bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db-lblchem-sec.properties" />

<bean id="dataSourceBase" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactoryBase" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceBase" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="cat.dinet.lblchem.sec.model" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props> 
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">${hibernate.connection.autocommit}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <qualifier value="sessionFactoryBase" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManagerBase" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactoryBase" />
    <qualifier value="transactionManagerBase" />
</bean>
```

JDBC Connection prperties:

> jdbc.driverClassName=net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver
>   jdbc.url=jdbc:ucanaccess://E:/lblchem32/data/lblchem-sec.mdb
>   jdbc.username=admin jdbc.password=
>
> hibernate.dialect=com.hxtt.support.hibernate.HxttAccessDialect
>   hibernate.show_sql=true hibernate.format_sql=true
>   hibernate.default_schema=public hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate
>   hibernate.connection.autocommit=false

Al construir el jar con Maven:

```
Hibernate: 
    create table HT_dn_sec_user (usr_id int not null, hib_sess_id CHAR(36) null)
Hibernate: 
    create table HT_dn_sec_user_role (uro_id int not null, hib_sess_id CHAR(36) null)
Hibernate: 
    create table HT_dn_sec_right (rig_id int not null, hib_sess_id CHAR(36) null)
Hibernate: 
    create table HT_dn_sec_role_right (rri_id int not null, hib_sess_id CHAR(36) null)
Hibernate: 
    create table HT_dn_sec_role (rol_id int not null, hib_sess_id CHAR(36) null)
....
```

También he construido varios tests junit:

```
@Test
public void getUserByLoginname() {
    DnSecUser obj = this.getDnSecUserDAO().getUserByLoginname("admin");
    System.out.println("admin has id=" + obj.getId());
    Assert.assertNotNull(obj);
}
```

con el siguiente output:

```
Hibernate: 
select
    dnsecuser0_.usr_id as usr_id1_6_,
    dnsecuser0_.usr_firstname as usr_fir19_6_,
    dnsecuser0_.usr_lastname as usr_las21_6_,
    dnsecuser0_.usr_loginname as usr_log22_6_,
    dnsecuser0_.usr_password as usr_pas24_6_,
....
    dnsecuser0_.version as version29_6_ 
from
    dn_sec_user dnsecuser0_ 
where
    dnsecuser0_.usr_loginname=?
admin has id=3
```

In the web app I there are a context.xml

```
<Context>
    ....
    <Resource name="jdbc/lblchem-sec" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
        driverClassName="net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver" 
        url="jdbc:ucanaccess://E:/lblchem32/data/lblchem-sec.mdb" 
        username="admin" password=""
        initialSize="5" maxActive="20" maxIdle="12" minIdle="8" timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="34000"
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="55000" validationQuery="SELECT 1" validationInterval="34000" testOnBorrow="true"
        removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="55" defaultAutoCommit="false" />
</Context>
```

On running Tomcat:

> 2018-02-23 11:54:46,906 DEBUG  [main] DatabaseImpl
>   M[readSystemCatalog] - Finished reading system catalog.  Tables:
>   [HT_dn_sec_right, HT_dn_sec_role, HT_dn_sec_role_right,
>   HT_dn_sec_user, HT_dn_sec_user_role, ..., dn_sec_right, dn_sec_role,
>   dn_sec_role_right, dn_sec_user, dn_sec_user_role, ...]
>   (Db=lblchem-sec.mdb)
>
> Hibernate: 
>       create table HT_dn_sec_user (usr_id int not null, hib_sess_id CHAR(36) null) Hibernate: 
>       create table HT_dn_sec_user_role (uro_id int not null, hib_sess_id CHAR(36) null) Hibernate: 
>       create table HT_dn_sec_right (rig_id int not null, hib_sess_id CHAR(36) null) Hibernate: 
>       create table HT_dn_sec_role_right (rri_id int not null, hib_sess_id CHAR(36) null) Hibernate: 
>       create table HT_dn_sec_role (rol_id int not null, hib_sess_id CHAR(36) null)

Pero cuando intento hacer el login login:

```
> Hibernate: 
>     select
>         dnsecuser0_.usr_id as usr_id1_6_,
>         dnsecuser0_.usr_firstname as usr_fir19_6_,
>         dnsecuser0_.usr_lastname as usr_las21_6_,
>         dnsecuser0_.usr_loginname as usr_log22_6_,
>         dnsecuser0_.usr_password as usr_pas24_6_,
>     ....
>         dnsecuser0_.version as version29_6_ 
>     from
>         dn_sec_user dnsecuser0_ 
>     where
>         dnsecuser0_.usr_loginname=? 2018-02-23 11:55:25,864 ERROR  [http-nio-8080-exec-5] SqlExceptionHelper M[logExceptions] -
> UCAExc:::4.0.3  user lacks privilege or object not found: DN_SEC_USER
```

He probado cambiar el formato de Access a accdb, cambiar parámetros de la conexión (memory=false; keepMirror=...) pero con los mismos resultados.

Se apreciará cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Finalmente he encontrado el error. Al definir el resource del jndiname en el archivo context.xml, había un error en la query de validación:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/MyDbSec" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
    driverClassName="net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver" 
    url="jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/data/myDb-sec.accdb" 
    username="" password=""
    initialSize="5" maxActive="20" maxIdle="12" minIdle="8" timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="34000"
    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="55000" validationQuery="SELECT 1" validationInterval="34000" testOnBorrow="true"
    removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="55" defaultAutoCommit="false" />
```

Habitualmente trabajo con PostgresSQL pero la query de validación para HSQLDB es la siguiente:

```
SELECT 1 FROM any_existing_table WHERE 1=0
```

(Naruralmente, hay que sustituir 'any_existing_table' por el nombre de una tabla que exista, me ha funcionado con el prefijo 'HT_' en el nombre.)

Finalmente, conecta y realiza correctamente las operaciones CRUD.
Quizá le sirva a alguien!